# How can I upgrade Opera 32-bit to Opera 64-bit and keep all my profile settings?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, browser, 32-bit, opera

I've been using Opera for years and have my preferences set exactly as I want them. How can I upgrade Opera 32-bit to Opera 64-bit and keep all my profile settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Opera 64-bit installs into "C:\Program Files\Opera x64", which will NOT transfer your settings. To get Opera to automatically use a profile from the 32-bit version, you need to click "Options" in the installer and **change the install path to "C:\Program Files\Opera"**.

Caveats:

- You can leave both versions installed, but with this setup you can't use them simultaneously. Whichever version (32- or 64-bit) you open first will be the one running until you close it, and trying to open the other version simply opens a tab in the version that's already running.
- The profile is share between the versions, so anything you do in one will be maintained when you close it and open the other.

Thanks to everyone in [this Opera forum post](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1432352&t=1365182633&page=1#comment12472402) for figuring this out.

Comment: You could also just transfer the exiting profile to the new installation location.

Comment: @Ramhound - That's definitely true. This way allows you to use them interchangeably and keep the same settings in both browsers going forward if you think you might still want/need the 32-bit version.

Comment: Go to opera:about and you'll find each browsers preference files. You can then copy them to the x64 profile location.